# Setup Django on Centos with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I am having a hard time to setup mod_wsgi on centos, I am keep getting the following error:

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

-----Sever Setup-----

```
Python Version: 2.6.6
Apache Version: 2.2.15
mod_wsgi: mod_wsgi-3.2-3.el6.x86_64
```

-----Apache Config "httpd.conf"-----

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/prj1/prj1/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/prj1
<Directory /home/prj1>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

-----Django  /home/prj1/prj1/wsgi.py-----

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/prj1')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "prj1.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: This SELinux was causing the problem, now problem solved! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

A quick dirty solution to disable the SELinux

echo 0 > /selinux/enforce

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good question for SO, but in any case: Does the user under which you run apache  has access to the /home/prj1 directory ? Try doing

```
chmod 755 -R /home/prgj1
```

as root.

Comment: I had even did chmod 777 -R /home/prj1, but this still will not solve the problem.